# How to achieve a gradient at the top and bottom for a shape in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

[image: Indented result]

I needed a shape which somewhat looks like a parentheses ( ).
I have tried with border modifier. With that, I was able to achieve a gradient effect at the top part of the shape.

```
                val styleModifier = Modifier.border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color.White,
                            Color.Gray
                        ),
                        startY = 100f,
                        endY = 500f,
                        tileMode = TileMode.Clamp
                    ),
                    SmootherShape(
                        slidingRadius,
                        slidingSmoothness
                    )
                )

           Box(
                Modifier
                    .then(styleModifier)
            )
```

Is there any way to achieve a gradient at the bottom similar to the top which will give a shape like ( ).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack you can apply to achieve your goal. That is to pass the list of five `colors` to the `gradient`.

It will look like below

[image: preview]

***Sample Code***

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun TestPreview() {
    val styleModifier = Modifier.border(
        width = 1.dp,
        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                Color.White,
                Color.Gray,
                Color.Gray,
                Color.Gray,
                Color.White
            ),
            tileMode = TileMode.Clamp
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp)
    )

    Box(
        Modifier
            .padding(15.dp)
            .size(150.dp)
            .then(styleModifier)
    )
}
```

Comment: The dark color I need to use is Color(0x1F2A2A2A). Unfortunately, This color will not give a proper result.

Comment: share your result what your get. I could check it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p97LcRu